# Pip cannot find a Version that satistfies the Requirement XX, (beatifulsoup4)

Tags: python, pip, installation

I use macOS and python 2.7.

When I try 'pip install beautifulsoup4' I get back:

> Collecting beautifulsoup4
>     Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement beautifulsoup4 (from versions: )
>   No matching distribution found for beautifulsoup4

also:

> You are using pip version 7.1.2, however version 10.0.1 is available.
>   You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.

If I try to upgrade I get back that requirments are already up-to-date.

How can install beatifulsoup4?

Comment: can you run `pip install beautifulsoup4 -vvv` and add the output to the question?

Answer (score 1):

You need to do pip3 install beautifulsoup4 or pip3 install bs4 to install BeautifulSoup4

and then you can just use it like this :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

Comment: From a search online I understood that pip3 specifies for python 3.x, and it should be 2.x instead, but pip2 does not work either.